# How to write if else statements in one line like a list comprehension but returns just a value with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working with a function and in a variable, I need a value instead of a list.

I used the following below

```py
value = project_list[0] if pathname=='/london' else project_list[1] if pathname=='/frankfurt'
```

But I am getting a `SyntaxError` what should I have done differently?

Comment: Try writing an actual if statement

Comment: You're missing an `else` for your second `if`.

Comment: its in a large function, cant I use a one liner?

Comment: The error comes from the second if clause not having a matching else in the ternary. Write out the if-else before consolidating it

Comment: oh, let me try again

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to write it multi line to be more readable.

```
...

if pathname == '/london':
  value = project_list[0]
elif pathname == '/frankfurt':
  value = project_list[1]
...
```

If you still prefer want it to be single liner, you can do like this(Formatted by black):

```
value = (
    project_list[0]
    if pathname == "/london"
    else project_list[1]
    if pathname == "/frankfurt"
    else something
)
```

Example:

```
pathname = '/london'
project_list = ['zero', 'first', 'second']
value = (
    project_list[0]
    if pathname == "/london"
    else project_list[1]
    if pathname == "/frankfurt"
    else project_list[2]
)
print(value)
```

Output -> `zero`

Comment: I prefer a one-liner. its going into a large function

Comment: Added the one liner as well. You have to replace `something` with the value you want.

Comment: Have you replaced `something`?

Comment: Let me try the new one

Comment: I have added a working example as well, it works just fine.

Comment: I resulted into creating a small function with your former approach to handle that section

Answer (score 1):

use a dictionnary as below - this is more readable than nested conditions

```
 value = {'/london' : project_list[0], '/franckfurt' : project_list[1]}.get(pathname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more else to complete the statement.

```
project_list = ['X', 'Y']
pathname = '/london'

value = project_list[0] if pathname=='/london' else project_list[1] if (pathname=='/frankfurt') else ''

print(value)
```